# Tensorflow: "AlreadyExistsError: Graph execution error:" when using residual blocks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am building a neural network based on GRU layers with Tensorflow subclassing. It works fine, except for when I include multiple custom residual blocks, i.e. let the input pass through a few layers and then add the input back to the output. The first epoch works fine, however, right after saving, before the second epoch starts, I get the following error:

```
AlreadyExistsError: Graph execution error:

Resource __per_step_0/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_add_163/tmp_var/frame:0/iter:0/struct tensorflow::TemporaryVariableOp::TmpVar
     [[{{node ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_add_163/tmp_var}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1954909]
```

Unfortunately, the full traceback does not provide anything helpful other than

```
in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb
```

and

```
in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50 try:
     51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     55   if name is not None:
```

I already found a similar issue on github, however, none of the suggested solutions helped me in the end.